# Java: standard library to convert field name ("firstName") to accessor method name ("getFirstName")

Tags: java

Is there a standard library (such as org.apache.commons.beanutils or java.beans) that will take a string field name and convert it to the standard method name? I'm looking all over and can't find a simple string conversion utility.

Comment: You can do that by yourself with 1 codeline.

Comment: +1, just what I was wondering. Even if it's trivial to write it yourself, it makes sense to use a standard lib utility if one exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A wild one-liner appeared!

```
String fieldToGetter(String name)
{
    return "get" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: +0: unless the getter is an "isBooleanGetter" ;)

Comment: @Peter good point, though not everyone uses the `isFoo()` naming convention for boolean field getters.

Comment: Actaully, I don't use the JavaBean getter/setters at all. I use `public Type field()` and `public void field(Type field)`

Comment: So you could use reflection to check if it an boolean and adapt your code to use is instead of get

Comment: WRONG! The getter for "eMail" is geteMail()!

Comment: @JRA_TLL that depends on what style you're using. If you're following [Google's camelization style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case) then the field should be called `email` and thus the getter `getEmail()`.

Comment: Well, it is a style question to avoid fields like eMail for the caveat mentioned. But as a fact, if you dare to name your field eMail than the getter/setter needs to be called geteMail to conform to the Java bean specification and e.g. to be found by Hibernate.

Comment: not true for converting attrs that have underscores in them. For example, proto will have underscores, corresponding java getters will be camel case

Comment: @JasmeetSingh I'm familiar with the proto underscore vs Java camel "behavior" but I don't see how that applies here, particularly given how broadly-state the original question is here. The original question implies that the input string will be in lower-camel case, not an arbitrary form.

Comment: @MattBall yes its implied and this answer is sufficient enough, but another answer will be to use Guava CaseFormat library

Answer (score 18):

The [JavaBean introspector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/introspection/index.html) is possibly the best choice. It handles "is" getters for boolean types and "getters" which take an argument and setters with none or two arguments and other edge cases. It is nice for getting a list of JavaBean fields for a class.

Here is an example,

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

public class SimpleBean
{
    private final String name = "SimpleBean";
    private int size;

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }

    public void setSize( int size )
    {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
            throws IntrospectionException
    {
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo( SimpleBean.class );
        for ( PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors() )
            System.out.println( pd.getName() );
    }
}
```

This prints

```
class
name
size
```

`class` comes from `getClass()` inherited from `Object`

EDIT: to get the getter or setter and its name.

```
public static String findGetterName(Class clazz, String name) throws IntrospectionException, NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Method getter = findGetter(clazz, name);
    if (getter == null) throw new NoSuchMethodException(clazz+" has no "+name+" getter");
    return getter.getName();
}

public static Method findGetter(Class clazz, String name) throws IntrospectionException, NoSuchFieldException {
    BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
    for ( PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors() )
        if (name.equals(pd.getName())) return pd.getReadMethod();
    throw new NoSuchFieldException(clazz+" has no field "+name);
}

public static String findSetterName(Class clazz, String name) throws IntrospectionException, NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException {
    Method setter = findSetter(clazz, name);
    if (setter == null) throw new NoSuchMethodException(clazz+" has no "+name+" setter");
    return setter.getName();
}

public static Method findSetter(Class clazz, String name) throws IntrospectionException, NoSuchFieldException {
    BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
    for ( PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors() )
        if (name.equals(pd.getName())) return pd.getWriteMethod();
    throw new NoSuchFieldException(clazz+" has no field "+name);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a code example of using `Introspector` to get a method name from a field name?

Comment: That's just the code from the tutorial you linked; show us how to write the method from `String` to `String` and you've got my +1.

Comment: A more difficult problem is using the getter name to get the method which is actually trivial using this approach.

Comment: Question is asking how to *generate* the strings "getClass", "getName" and "getSize", given the strings "class", "name", and "size". You're answering how to retrieve already existing methods.

Comment: @strickli for boolean fields, the method name could be `isFlag` or `getFlag` which the introspector to work out for you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Indeed it could...however, that's still not what the question is asking.
An introspector will _introspect_ an existing bean, with existing methods. The questioner is asking how to generate method names that don't yet exist.

Answer (score 16):

You can use a [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) without an `Inspector` (which was suggested by Peter):

```
final PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = 
    new PropertyDescriptor("name", MyBean.class);
System.out.println("getter: " + propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().getName());
System.out.println("setter: " + propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod().getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String fieldToSetter(String name)
{
    return "set" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}
```

With copyright by Matt Ball

Comment: Is that a copy-paste-change-1-character version of my answer? :P

Comment: I would have been able to write it by myself, but I didn't want to confuse the OP with different syntax :P

Answer (score 1):

I modified the methods above, to remove the underscore character and capitalize the next character... for instance, if the field name is "validated_id", then the getter method name will be "getValidatedId"

```
private String fieldToGetter(String name) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("_(\\w)").matcher(name);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        name = name.replaceFirst(matcher.group(0), matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }

    return "get" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}

private String fieldToSetter(String name) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("_(\\w)").matcher(name);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        name = name.replaceFirst(matcher.group(0), matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }

    return "set" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Guava CaseFormat will do it for you.

For example from lower_underscore -> LowerUnderscore

```
CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, str)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String fieldToGetter(Field field) {
    final String name = field.getName();
    final boolean isBoolean = (field.getType() == Boolean.class || field.getType() == boolean.class);
    return (isBoolean ? "is" : "get") + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}

String fieldToGetter(boolean isBoolean, String name) {
    return (isBoolean ? "is" : "get") + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example two fields named `example` and `eXample` have the getters
`getExample` and `geteExample` **IF** generated by eclipse. BUT this is not compatible with `PropertyDescriptor("eXample",...).getReadMethod().getName()` which expects `getEXample` as a valid getter name.

```
public class XX {

    private Integer example;
    private Integer eXample;


    public Integer getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public Integer geteXample() {
        return eXample;
    }

    public void setExample(Integer example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public void seteXample(Integer eXample) {
        this.eXample = eXample;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Getter: " + new PropertyDescriptor("example", ReflTools.class).getReadMethod().getName());
            System.out.println("Getter: " + new PropertyDescriptor("eXample", ReflTools.class).getReadMethod().getName());
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```