# Loop on Class Members and write to Excel Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an array list of custom objects. I am trying to loop on these objects to write my output to an excel file.

In my code below, in the first loop, I set the header row in the excel file by looping over the class member variables. In the second loop, I write the object values.

My code:

```
class ChecklistOutput {
    //Instantiating class data members
String a, b, c;

public ChecklistOutput() { 
     a = ""; b = ""; c = ""; }
}

private static ArrayList<ChecklistOutput> MasterOutput = new ArrayList<ChecklistOutput>();

private static void writeToMasterExcel() {
    ChecklistOutput obj1 = new ChecklistOutput();
    obj1.a = "AA"; obj1.b = "BB"; obj1.c = "CC"; 
    ChecklistOutput obj1 = new ChecklistOutput();
    obj2.a = "AA"; obj2.b = "BB"; obj2.c = "CC";
    ChecklistOutput obj1 = new ChecklistOutput();
    obj3.a = "AA"; obj3.b = "BB"; obj3.c = "CC"; 
    ChecklistOutput obj1 = new ChecklistOutput();
    obj4.a = "AA"; obj4.b = "BB"; obj4.c = "CC"; 

    MasterOutput.add(obj1);
    MasterOutput.add(obj2);
    MasterOutput.add(obj3);
    MasterOutput.add(obj4);
    System.out.println(MasterOutput.size());

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = null;
    HSSFRow row = null;
    HSSFCell cell = null;
    int rownum = 0, cellnum = 0;
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("Master Spreadsheet");
    row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    System.out.println("rownum " + rownum);
    Class<?> c = new ChecklistOutput().getClass();
    Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

    // First loop
    for (Field field : fields) {
        cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(field.getName());
        cellnum += 1;
    }
    System.out.println(MasterOutput.size());
    // Second loop
    for (ChecklistOutput x : MasterOutput) {
        // This prints 4 times meaning that there are 4 values in
        // MasterOutput
        System.out.println("Hell");
        rownum += 1;
        cellnum = 0;
        row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            try {
                // I can see values here
                System.out.println(field.get(x).toString());
                cell.setCellValue(field.get(x).toString());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cellnum += 1;
        }
    }
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    try {
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\Checklist-Output.xls",
                true));
        workbook.write(bos);
        bos.close();
        workbook.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I only get the header values in my excel file.

Output:

```
| a | b | c |
```

Can someone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just a case of your `MasterOutput` list being empty? Also, you're resetting your `cellnum` in the wrong place. It should be in the outer loop instead of the inner loop.

Comment: I agree. Also you should rename the field to `masterOutput' to follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: I checked MasterOutput and it has 4 values.

Comment: Do all the `ChecklistOutput` instances in your `MasterOutput` list contain emtpy strings for the `A`, `B` and `C` values (as initialized by the constructor)?

Comment: No. In fact none of them are empty strings. I have values stored in the instances and I can see them when I print it. I have updated the code for the same.

Comment: I've tried your code. Except for some obvious mistakes (`obj2`, `obj3` and `obj4` are not declared), it works just fine for me. Are you sure that you're looking at the correct output file?

Comment: I updated the answer to keep your looping structure. Made a slight mistake with rownum previously

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int col = 0; col < fields.length; col++) {
    Field field = fields[col];
    HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(rownum);
    if (header == null) {
        header = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    }
    HSSFCell cell = header.createCell(col);
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(field.getName());
}
for (ChecklistOutput x : MasterOutput) {
    rownum += 1;
    HSSFRow rowData = sheet.getRow(rownum);
    if (rowData == null) {
        rowData = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < fields.length; col++) {
        Field field = fields[col];
        HSSFCell cellData = rowData.createCell(col);
        cellData.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        try {
            // I can see values here
            System.out.println(field.get(x).toString());
            cellData.setCellValue(field.get(x).toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also i recommend you use a POJO instead of ChecklistOutput (private fields with getters and setters).
I did the same thing you did. If you want the values for the fields from a pojo you can use reflection to invoke the getters. You can look into  [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771370/is-there-a-better-way-of-obtaining-an-objects-field-getters-other-than-java-ref) . It asks for something else, but provides a working example to get the values with reflection (i used it for POI as well).