# Find value of object by field name in Java

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
private String Foo;
private String Bar;
//Getters, Setters, Constructors
}
```

and I have an object:

```
MyClass object1 = new MyClass("Text1", "Text2");
```

Now, I have an XML with field name, something like that:

```
<item ... fieldName="Foo" ... />
```

I want to get value from object by fieldName from XML (Reflection?)

I tried something like that:

```
    String[] array = { /* fieldNames from XML */ };
    for(Field f : object1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        for(String s : array){
            if(f.getName() == s )
                //How to get value?
        }
    }
```

but I don't know how to push it further.

Comment: I posted a question on something different, but it does provide a functioning example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771370/is-there-a-better-way-of-obtaining-an-objects-field-getters-other-than-java-ref . Your value will be val = method.invoke(obj); It has inside this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503412/java-standard-library-to-convert-field-name-firstname-to-accessor-method-na/5503534#5503534 ) which describes the methods i call to find the getter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're after, but if you want to call method by having it's name as string, that's how you'd do it:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("foo", "bar");
Method method = myClass.getClass().getMethod("getFoo");
String string = (String) method.invoke(myClass);
```

Surround that with try catch blocks

Comment: Excellent! Work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String fieldName = (String) field.get(objec1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have accepted an answer,it works by method reflection which have some drawback,like performance overhead or retriving the correct getter from a field name.
I would go for the field reflection as you where doing in the code:

```
for(String s:array){
    Field myField = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(s);
    String myVal =(String) myField.get(obj);
    /*Your code with the myVal....*/
}
```

Look also for the [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) javadoc.